# Referencing elements of ArrayRules

Tags: formatting, syntax

How do I call elements of `ArrayRules` by their indices rather than by `Part[ArrayRules[list],i]`? I'd like to call the element that looks like `{i, j}-> val`by referring to the pair `{i, j}` rather than by a single numerical index denoting the location within the list. 
The reason for this is I would like to create a new `SparseArray` based on the elements of a list, but I can't figure out how to change `val` in `ArraryRules` while preserving the rules that map it to a `SparseArray`.

I'd like to call a specific element `{i, j}` and assign the rules `{i, j}-> newval`

Comment: Can't you just do `sparse[[i,j]]=newval`...?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Not for what I'm doing. I'm taking a subset of a list and modifying it and then replacing that part of the original list, so I need to be able to pull individual elements by their indices.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Could you add a minimal working example to your question?

Comment: @TeeJay, Something like `Normal@KeyTake[atest, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}]`? for `{1,1}` and `{2,2}` elements as axample?

Comment: `arrayrules /. ({i, j} -> _) :> {i, j} -> newval` or `arrayrules /. (idx -> _) :> idx -> newval`, where `idx` is the `{i,j}` pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware that you can define a Rule to specify a change of Rules ?

For example here is a replacement of the value indexed by {1,1} :

```
{{1, 1} -> 2, {1, 2} -> 3} /.  ({1, 1} -> _) -> ({1, 1} -> XXX)
```

> {{1, 1} -> XXX, {1, 2} -> 3}

Answer (score 2):

```
(* make a dummy example array *)
test = RandomInteger[10, {5, 5}];

(* get rules *)
atest = ArrayRules[test];

(* Prefix with our replacements - the default behavior *)
(* for sparse array is to ignore subsequent duplicate positions *)

patest = SparseArray[Join[{{1, 1} -> -1, {2, 2} -> -2}, atest]];

(* show result *)
test
patest // Normal
```

> {{1,2,8,2,10},{10,8,6,7,10},{3,1,7,5,8},{8,8,3,0,0},{6,10,4,4,0}}
>
> {{-1,2,8,2,10},{10,-2,6,7,10},{3,1,7,5,8},{8,8,3,0,0},{6,10,4,4,0}}